# AmplifyJS not storing JavaScript array in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage, amplifyjs

I am experiencing an issue with AmplifyJS where I am storing an Array of Arrays into local storage, set with the key of `product_array_to_add` and when I then try and access it with:

`var prod_array = amplify.store('product_array_to_add');`

I get an empty array.

```
// this code works
var product_ids = amplify.store('product_ids_to_add').split(':');
console.log(product_ids);

// both console output statements produce empty arrays
var prod_array = amplify.store('product_array_to_add'); 
console.log(prod_array);
console.dir(prod_array);
```

The below code is how I am *setting* the values:

```
amplify.store('product_ids_to_add', product_ids);
amplify.store('product_array_to_add', ProductsArr);
```

Does AmplifyJS have an issue with storing an Array of Arrays? Is there any other reason why I can't access the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found that the problem was down to the fact that I wasn't pushing JS objects into the array. So I changed my code to do exactly that and Amplify was quite happy to allow me to retrieve the data at the other end.

```
var ProductsArr = new Array();

$.each($("#container .product"), function(){

   productObj = {       
      name: $(this).find('.prod_name').text(),
      code: $(this).find('.prod_code').text(),
      price: parseInt($(this).find('.prod_price').text()),
      prod_id: $(this).find('.size_select').val()                       
   };

   ProductsArr.push(productObj);        

});

amplify.store('product_array_to_add', ProductsArr);
```